# What normalization rules does this table break

Tags: normalization, relational-theory, eav

Our previous DBA got fed up with the development teams frequent requests to change the database schema to add and delete columns. He then advised to the developers that he would create simple tables with the following definition.

```
+---------------+---------+
| Record Number | VarChar |
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | VarChar |
+---------------+---------+
| Column Value  | VarChar |
+---------------+---------+
```

So if the developers wanted a table which **normally** look like the following

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Employee ID | Employee Name | Employee Salary |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 0001        | John Doe      | 100000.00       |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 0002        | Jane Doe      | 110000.00       |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 0003        | Jack Doe      | 120000.00       |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

They could add rows in the following fashion

```
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| Record Number | Column Name     | Column Value |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1             | Employee ID     | 0001         |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1             | Employee Name   | John Doe     |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1             | Employee Salary | 100000.00    |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 2             | Employee ID     | 0002         |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 2             | Employee Name   | Jane Doe     |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 2             | Employee Salary | 110000.00    |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 3             | Employee ID     | 0003         |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 3             | Employee Name   | Jack Doe     |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 3             | Employee Salary | 120000.00    |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

This obviously does not meet the smell test, and makes me want to analyze what [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would such a setup break.

Does this break [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)? [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)? [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)? [BCNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)? Explanations would be nice.

Comment: this is known as an [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model) and it basically breaks every normal form

Comment: EAV can do anything, badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a terrible pattern, but it doesn't actually break any normalization rules.  The reason is that it's actually a change in *what* you are modeling.  Instead of your database modeling, say, Employees, it models Entities, Attributes, and Values.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it "a terrible pattern", since this has it uses (https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway)

Comment: @David Browne: I agree it's like lazily saying that entities have various attributes with values. With out taking the trouble to investigate what those attributes actually are and what data type and constraints can those value have.

Comment: In terms of RDBMS the table represents a type. EAV is an approach to use RDBMS for data that has no strict (or any) type. EAV is a meta-type that violate the main principle of the relational algebra: each entity is represented by single tuple. Instead  EAV represents the entity as the set of rows that make impossible to use relational algebra. EAV-related code can mimic the relational algebra but that is just kind of hack. RDBMS should be replaced by more suitable tool if EAV is emerged. Sure if such kind of tool exists.

Comment: eav is really inconveient to work with, if your database supports free-form structured types like XML or JSON use one of them and put one entitiy in each row,

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David Browne's answer and Lamak's comment. They helped me a lot to do my analysis.

As Lamak mentioned in his comment, such a model is known as an [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Although the EAV model may not break any normalization rules, it should mostly be used to model entities where the number of attributes (properties, parameters) that can be used to describe them is potentially vast, but the number that will actually apply to a given entity is relatively modest. EAV models are an efficient way to store data, but they are inefficient and difficult to query.

In situations where the **domain's entities have well defined attributes**, a [Relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) is far more superior and desirable. When such a model is implemented in a [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), users can leverage powerful RDBMS features like efficient storage techniques and powerful querying abilities.

Answer (score 0):

For me it breaks the first normal form.

Why?  **"Column Value"** does not represent a unique domain of values (in this case: **ID, name** and **salary** are different data types: int, character and decimal).

So, an example would be something as simple as calculating the `SUM()` of the salaries, you have to do a complex query for this.